# Drupal newsletter module

Tags: drupal, module, newsletter

I am looking for a module / plugin Drupal that will send automatically e-mail newsletter every tot minutes and only when there are new articles.
Is this a good one to do that ?

https://drupal.org/project/newsletter

Answer (score 2):

The Simplenews module will do that: https://drupal.org/project/simplenews . It has rules integration that will allow you to send the newsletters out automatically.

You may also want to set up Mandrill account and use the Mandrill module https://drupal.org/project/mandrill if you're going to be sending out a lot of e-mails.